# Remove TrueCrypt encrypted partition

Tags: partitioning, truecrypt, gparted

I have a laptop that someone gave me to reinstall windows on. The problem is, it's encrypted with TrueCrypt and they do not know the password.

So I figured I would just boot up gparted and remove all the partitions and install windows. However, gparted has a problem seeing partitions saying 
"gparted invalid partition table recursive partition". It's also saying the HDD is only 198MB.

What can I do to remove/delete the encrypted partition table?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot by chance?  Just so we have an idea of what you are looking at exactly.  I presume this is the system drive that is encrypted?

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/265008/remove-truecrypt-whole-usb-encryption-in-linux) about some options on how to remove the partition table.  Gparted does not support Truecrypt volumes hence the reason you run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like DBAN (Darik's Boot and Nuke) (http://www.dban.org/)  to clean off the disk before using it for anything else.

Comment: Have you used DBAN in a situation similar to this?  There any special steps the author has to do so it will work?  Be specific.

Comment: There is nothing special that needs to be done. DBAN ignores anything on the disk and wipes it clean no matter what.

Comment: Trying the DBAN now, estimating about 5 hours remaining.

Comment: Doing the job it does takes time. I have cleaned off disks that took several days to complete.